# How to calculate closed-loop bandwidth from open-loop parameters using feedback factor

Tags: feedback, negative-feedback

I'm working through a past feedback analysis question for an exam and trying to calculate what the closed-loop bandwidth becomes given the open-loop gain \$|Av|=10^5\$, open-loop bandwidth \$B_{wo} = 20 \text{ Hz}\$ and a calculated feedback factor \$ \beta = 0.151515 \$. The class notes I'm given don't mention anything about how this works and neither does the textbook. From what I understand introducing negative feedback reduces the systems gain and widens its bandwidth? The answer given is that the closed-loop bandwidth becomes approximately \$303 \text{ kHz}\$. I initially thought to multiply the feedback factor with the open-loop bandwidth giving \$3.03 \text{Hz}\$, three orders of magnitude too small.

I have looked at this post  [Closed loop bandwidth vs open loop bandwidth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70615/closed-loop-bandwidth-vs-open-loop-bandwidth)
but I would like to know specifically how to calculate the closed-loop bandwidth using this feedback fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you have in terms of open loop gain: -

[image]

You have an open-loop gain of 100,000 (100 dB) from DC to 20 Hz then it rolls off at 20 dB per decade until it reaches unity gain at 2 MHz.

With a feedback factor of 0.151515, the gain of the op-amp is the reciprocal i.e. 6.6. A gain of 6.6 is 16.4 dB hence, I've drawn an orange line across the graph at this point and it intersects the open loop gain a bit above 200 kHz.

Hopefully this makes sense now.

To get to 303 kHz you calculate the fraction of a decade above 200 kHz that the orange line intersects the open-loop line. I estimate it to be about 0.18 based on 1 - 16.4/20.

Take the antilog of 0.18 and multiply it by 200 kHz to get the real frequency number where the vertical orange line hits the base line. The answer I get is 302.7 kHz.

Answer (score 4):

I'm too lazy to draw a new picture so I got a suitable one from the web:

[image]

Given is that \$A = 10^5\$

Open loop bandwidth: \$B_{wo} = 20 \text{ Hz}\$

Feedback: \$ \beta = 0.151515 \$

From this I can derive that the closed loop gain. As long as \$A\$ is much larger than the closed loop gain, I can use gain = \$ 1/\beta = 6.6 \$
Indeed that's much smaller than \$10^5\$ so that was a valid way to do it.

Since this will be a first order system (no other cutoff points are mentioned) above 20 Hz the open loop gain will decrease with 20 dB / decade and that means if the frequency **increases** with a factor \$x\$ then the gain will **decrease** with a factor \$x\$.

So for this kind of system the gain * bandwidth product remains constant. So at 20 Hz you'd get that \$10^5\$ times gain but at 200 Hz you'd get \$10^4\$ etc..

In this case the gain has decreased by a factor \$10^5 / 6.6 = 15151\$ so the bandwidth will increase with the same factor: \$15151 * 20 = 303 \$ kHz

Answer (score 2):

Blargian - At first, I completely agree with Andy aka`s answer.

However, what will be your answer if during exam the question will arise WHY the closed-loop bandwidth will be at the frequency where the orange line intersects the open-loop gain of the opamp?

In case you know the answer, stop reading now. But if you are not sure about the answer continue the reading:

The key to the answer is a term that was not yet mentioned: **LOOP GAIN LG(jw)** (that is the gain of the complete  feedback loop if it is open).

In your case it is simply **LG(jw)=Av(jw)*beta**.

The magnitude of the loop gain LG can also be found in the magnitude diagram for Av(w) (see the diagram from Andy aka) because of **LG=Av(w)/(1/beta)**.

That means in dB: **LG(w) in dB = Av(w) in dB - (1/beta) in dB.**

(Comment: For a non-inverting amplifier 1/beta is identical to the closed-loop gain, see Andy aka`s nomenclature)

In the mentioned diagram, this function is shown, if you consider the orange line as a **new abscissa** (new frequency axis). This means: The loop gain LG (magnitude) is identical to the varying distance between the Av(w) curve and the orange line.

And it is important to realize that at the **crossing point** the loop gain is 0dB (equal to **unity**).

Why is this important? Analyze the closed-loop gain formula for negative feedback:

**Acl(jw)**=Av(jw)/[1+Av(jw)*beta)]=**Av(jw)/[1+LG(jw)]**.

The magnitude of this complex function for Av(jw) will be **3 dB** down (definition of **closed-loop bandwidth**) when the magnitude of the denominator will be SQRT(2). Hence, the closed-loop BW will be at that frequency where the magnitude of the loop gain is LG=1 (0 dB).

This is - as mentioned above - the **crossing point** between the orange line and the magnitude function for Av(jw).